# Grails 2.0.0: HTTP status 302

Tags: grails, post, controller, get, httpresponse

I have a controller which allows only POST for certain actions:

```
static allowedMethods = [save: "POST", update: "POST", delete: "POST"]
```

Then there's a test for it:

```
void testUpdateWithGet() {
    controller.update()
    assert response.status == HttpServletResponse.SC_METHOD_NOT_ALLOWED
}
```

This worked fine with 2.0.0.RC1 but after upgrading to Grails 2.0.0 final release the returned status in the response is `302`. Why is that?

Regards

Jonas

Comment: If I explicitly set the method I get the same `request.method = "GET"`.  Some similar tests even return `200` which means the call is OK.

Comment: Worth mentioning that the `save` actions return 200 and the `update` and `delete` 302 for all controllers.

Comment: Given that if I test this issue not from unit tests but from the commandline via curl and I am unable to reproduce your 302s, I would guess there is something amiss with how calling the method directly is handled.
I would suggest removing your allowedMethods criteria and printing out request.method in your controller and then run your test. Just so that you can see what the default is.

Comment: @JanWikholm - default method is always GET.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I can confirm your test case. It's because since 2.0.0.RC3 Grails has unresolved bug that affects 2.0.0 final too: http://jira.grails.org/browse/GRAILS-8426 - Allowed methods are not respected in unit tests. You can downgrade to 2.0.0.RC1 or wait for this bug to be fixed. It only affects unit tests, but works fine in application.

Comment: Thanks, for some reason I expected that. I upgraded to RC3 a while back and saw the issue and downgraded to RC1 again. But now that the final release is out I don't wanna downgrade anymore. So, I am happy to wait for the bug being resolved. I adjusted my unit tests with a big comment...